# Can't remove SHIMANO Nexus FC-C6000 Crankset

Tags: shimano, nexus

I'm stuck trying to remove my SHIMANO Nexus FC-C6000 Crank from the SHIMANO BB-UN55 bottom bracket. I've removed the bolts fine but can't get the cranks apart. Any suggestions?

[image: crankset]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a crank puller.  It threads in to the crank arm, and presses on the bottom bracket spindle to pull the arms off.

[image: Park Tool Crank Puller for Square Taper Cranks]

http://www.parktool.com/product/crank-puller-for-square-taper-cranks-ccp-22

A video here from Park Tool on using their crank puller:

Comment: This answer is totally correct - you can buy one as pictured, or a smaller one that uses a spanner or big hex key.  If this is a one-time thing you might hire one, but as grandad said "New job new tool"  These tools often also fit exercise equipment.   Just be careful that the threads are fully engaged as much as possible, there are large forces at work.  When you refit, apply some copperslip or some grease to make it easier for the next time.